# Is there an easy way to reference dataset in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to BiqQuery and have to write large queries referencing several tables from a single dataset.

Is there an easy way to declare a dataset in beginning of a SELECT query and just use table names through out query? Or maybe use dataset name as a variable and use var.Table.column?

I tried to do `USE projectName.dataSet;` but found that USE does not work in BigQuery SQL.

I tried `DECLARE DS STRING DEFAULT 'projectName.dataSet';` using both single codes and ticks in different way, but am getting NOT FOUND error.

Is there an easy way to write query other than writing `projectName.dataSet.Table` every time, and just mention `Table`?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
set @@dataset_project_id = 'projectName';
set @@dataset_id = 'dataSet';
select ... from `Table`
```

Comment: Thanks! however I am not able to declare variables after this as variable declaration are only allowed at the start, and the declarations are using the dataset so I need set first.

Comment: not sure what/how this related to your initial question :o) anyway - you asked - we answered!